# One To Many : Display Criterias in each categories using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Please help.. I just want to display and organize the categories and each criteria under the specifi category

I have this code in my controller

```
public function readCriteria(Request $req)
{
    $dataCategories = Category::all();;
    $catCriteria = [];
    foreach ($dataCategories as $dataCategory) {
       array_push($catCriteria,DB::table('criterias')
       ->where('cat_id', $dataCategory->id)
       ->get());
    }      
     return view('admin.criterias', compact('dataCategories')) -> with('catCriteria',collect($catCriteria));

}
```

and in my view is this

```
@foreach($dataCategories as $dataCategory)
    <div class="col-lg-3">      
            <div class="panel-body">                
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        {{$dataCategory->cat_name}}
                        {{$dataCategory->id}}
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        @forelse($catCriteria->where('cat_id',$dataCategory->id) as $criteria)
                        {{ $criteria->cri_name }} : {{ $criteria->cri_points }}
                        <br>
                        @empty
                        <em>No Data</em>
                        @endforelse             
                        </div>

                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>  
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Do you have relationships between the categories and the data ?

Comment: yes... id is my primary key in Categories and cat_id is my foriegn key in criteria.

Comment: I mean in the Model !

Comment: No.. I do not have relationships on it.. I just want to query the categories together with the criterias.. can you help me?

Comment: Ok for your case one category has many criterias ? and criteria belongs to one category or it can belongs to many categories ?

Comment: criteria only belongs to one category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the better choice is to use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) :

Add the following methods :

- **Category Model :**

  ```
  public function criterias()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Criteria', 'cat_id');
  }
  ```
- **Criteria Model :**

  ```
  public function category()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'cat_id');
  }
  ```

With this relationships, in the controller you can simply do like this :

```
public function readCriteria(Request $req)
{
    $dataCategories = Category::with('criterias')->get();  

    return view('admin.criterias', compact('dataCategories'));
}
```

And in the view all you will do is :

```
@foreach($dataCategories as $dataCategory)
<div class="col-lg-3">      
    <div class="panel-body">                
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{$dataCategory->cat_name}}
                {{$dataCategory->id}}
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                @forelse($dataCategory->criterias as $criteria)
                    {{ $criteria->cri_name }} : {{ $criteria->cri_points }}
                <br>
                @empty
                    <em>No Data</em>
                @endforelse             
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
@endforeach
```

Comment: Happy to help :)